# Есть ли аналог MemoryStream?

Tags: c++

Есть ли в `C++` аналог `MemoryStream` из `.NET`? Если нету - может быть у кого-то есть собственные разработки реализации `MemoryStream`, прошу поделиться ими.

p.s. очень хотелось бы реализацию как в `.NET`, она привычнее гораздо чем аналогичная с `cin\cout`.

Comment: В `glibc` есть `FILE *open_memstream(char **ptr, size_t *sizeloc);`. Но подойдет ли он Вам?

Comment: @avp, думаю что не подойдет, мне поток работы с памятью нужен для формирования пакетов, состоящих из байт. Работа с файлами не нужна.

Comment: Это же просто файловый интерфейс для fputc/fprintf/fwrite..., который вместо файла пишет байты в  память (после fflush/fclose видите их в количестве `sizeloc`  по адресу `*ptr`) (думал очевидно...)

Comment: @avp, очивидно для закоренелого сишника, а не человека, который с комфортного, рационального и удобного дотнета даунгрейднулся на плюсы)

Comment: @avp, посмотрел доки, не хотелось бы с собой таскать либу от линукса. Проект рассчитан только под Windows.

Comment: Ну, я же и говорил, что сомневаюсь, подойдет ли (не хочу тут спорить о красоте, рациональности и т.п. разных систем программирования) для винды...

Comment: @avp, никто и не собирается спорить. Это уже давно признано под Windows как аксиома большинством пользователей EN SO, пруф тут: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145110/c-performance-vs-java-c

Comment: Причем тут это? Я имел в виду \*nix (а вообще, на SO все же специфический контингент и не уверен, что  всем суждениям тут и там (enSO) нужно доверять)

Comment: @avp, не обращайти внимание, считайте что это "крик души". Многие кричат "дотнет фигня, плюсы форевер") А по факту, как только копнул чуть глубже - ситуация строго наоборот.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Есть [`stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream), при использовании стандартных потоков он является аналогом `MemoryStream`.

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << 1;
assert(ss.str() == "1");
```

Comment: Подождем, может быть кто-то поделится своей реализацией. Если других ответов не будет - приму Ваш как правильный.

Answer (score 1):

Как часный случай, в Windows есть `IStream`. На базе `IStream` можно создать поток в памяти с помощью ф-ции `CreateStreamOnHGlobal`. Нужно это при использовании OLE, RichEdit, GDI+, встроеных протоколов mk,http,ftp  и многих других библиотек винды.

```
HANDLE m = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED,size);    
IStream * stm = 0;
HRESULT result = CreateStreamOnHGlobal(m,0,&stm);
if (result != S_OK) { GlobalFree(m); return result;}
```

Как минус - отсутствие "автоувеличения" размера. Для последнего нужно самому писать реализацию IStream.

Answer (score 1):

`MemoryStream` сам по себе - ерунда. Кому может понадобиться работать с массивом байт через настолько сложный интерфейс? :)

Весь смысл `MemoryStream` - в реализации интерфейса `Stream` (притом реализация, на самом деле, тривиальна). А потому, чтобы найти аналог `MemoryStream` - надо сначала найти аналог `Stream`.

Для файловых потоков аналогом `MemoryStream` будет [`std::stringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/). Учитывая, что в C++ нет различия между символом и байтом - это практически прямой аналог.

Для Qt аналогом абстрактного потока данных будет [`QIODevice`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qiodevice.html), а аналогом `MemoryStream` - [`QBuffer`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qbuffer.html). Также в роли обертки более высокого уровня можно использовать [`QDataStream`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdatastream.html) - его можно формировать сразу вокруг Qt-массива (сильно подозреваю, что при этом внутрях именно QBuffer и будет создан - сам бы я так и поступил).

Comment: Ну это Вы зря. Очень даже удобная вещь именно для приема\передачи байт. Грубо говоря, на примере .NET реализации: создаем класс сетевого пакета, наследуемся от MemoryStream, переопределяем методы Read\Write, определяем методы (Write\Read Little\Big Endian). И имеет по существу очень многое со сравнительно небольшим колл-вом кода. Это требуется конечно в крупных проектах, из-за передачи пары байт смысла его реализации понятное дело нет.

Comment: По сути конечно можно самому написать нечто подобное, но, боюсь не хватит знаний в C++, очень легко наделать ошибок, а потом удивляться почему приложение падает. Ну и нативная отладка оставляет желать лучшего... Поэтому и не рискнул писать сам подобную вещь.

Comment: @Alexis Это все можно проделывать над *любым* потоком - например, непосредственно над сетевым. Кстати, рекомендую посмотреть на классы [`BinaryReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.binaryreader(v=vs.110).aspx)/[`BinaryWriter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.binarywriter(v=vs.110).aspx) - это удобнее чем постоянно писать свои методы. Работают в режиме Little Endian.

Comment: На .NET проект уже готов. Портирую потихоньку на плюсы и стараюсь подстроиться под архитектуру уже имеющегося кода. BinaryReader/BinaryWriter - это дотнет и в данном случае не подходит, но на будущее учту. Спасибо.

Comment: `Кому может понадобиться работать с массивом байт через настолько сложный интерфейс?` Тому, кто пишет чистый код при помощи TDD. Класс принимает `std::iostream` в конструкторе(Dependency Injection). В тестах внедряется `std::stringstream`. После секции arrange в тесте, стрим проверяется на наличие или отсутствие чего-то в нем. Получаются маленькие быстрые юнит-тесты, где тебе не надо создавать реальные файлы на реальном диске и юзать целую файловую систему системы, на которой работаешь. В продакшине просто передаешь то что тебе надо: файл, нетворк стрим, что бы то ни было.

Comment: Реальные случаи применения из того что помню прямо сейчас: сериалайзинг, шифрование данных.

Comment: @KulaGGin *"Получаются маленькие быстрые юнит-тесты, где тебе не надо создавать реальные файлы на реальном диске и юзать целую файловую систему системы, на которой работаешь."* - иными словами, основной режим всё-таки работа с файлами/сетью/чем-то ещё, а работа с массивом как с файлом идёт для однообразия. Ровно то о чём я писал.

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся со схожей проблемой, нашел нечто подходящее в [библиотеке Poco](https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.BasicMemoryStreamBuf.html)